# Anime where the mc collects stones

Tags: story-identification, anime

I was little when i saw this anime where the protagonist collects stones which the starting letter goes to a letter in his country's name.
For example O for Opal
D for Diamond
And he is searching for them
I remember there being a mist of some sort

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Wrong answers give you a good chance to [edit] further details into your question, e.g. "I know it can't be *Tinker Quest* because the game I was playing didn't have a Lithuanian Peddler as a main character and I never owned a TG-16 with the Rumble Pak."

Answer (score 2):

Might this be *[Deltora Quest](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(anime))*, an anime based on the children's book series?

[image: Title card for Deltora Quest]

> The seven gems of the Belt of Deltora are stolen by the evil Shadow Lord and scattered, hidden in the most feared places in Deltora and the Shadow Lord overtakes the land. King Endon, who was supposed to protect the Belt whose magic power protects Deltora, somehow vanish from the land to leave his people in the mercy of the tyrant for 16 years.
>
> On Lief's sixteenth birthday after narrowly escaping the Grey Guards, he is presented with the Belt of Deltora, given a task to gather the 7 gems and to find the heir to the throne in order to rid Deltora of the evil Shadow Lord once and for all. He is also given a sword, an invisibility cloak, a rough map of where the gems were to be and a travelling companion named Barda who was long known as a beggar before revealing himself as one of the palace guards. He and Barda leave city of Del and enter the Forests of Silence where they are attacked by the Wenn and paralysed. They are woken up by a mysterious girl named Jasmine, who at first believed them as Grey Guards and only intended to rob them and leave them to be eaten by the Wennbar. However, after being persuaded by an old tree that told her that they were not Grey Guards, she comes and saves them with an antidote that freed them from the paralysis.

Each gem in the [Belt of Deltora](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Belt_of_Deltora) maps out to a tribe and, as noted [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172459/book-series-where-they-collect-either-stones-or-gems/172494#172494), the gem names spell out "Deltora".

> The Deltora series follows the protagonists' quest to restore the "belt of Deltora" with seven gems: **D**iamond, **E**merald, **L**apis Lazuli, **T**opaz, **O**pal, **R**uby, **A**methyst.

### Trailer

The mist bit might be from [The Valley of the Lost](https://deltoraquest.fandom.com/wiki/Lief#The_Valley_of_the_Lost):

> Failing to convince them, he offered Dain the chance to rejoin him, which the boy accepted, and also gave Jasmine a hat to conceal her hair and make the group less conspicuous. They were then surprised when Neridah refused to rejoin them, with Doom deducing that she would attempt to travel with Lief's party. As expected she attempted this and eventually won them over, but quickly wore out her welcome, prompting the companions to attempt to lose her by leaving for the Valley while she is asleep. Reaching it, they left Kree and Filli behind due to a toxic mist that filled the Valley, and entered it to find it filled with ghostly people. They then met the ruler of the Valley, a sorcerer known as the Guardian, whose magic bound the companions and Neridah, who was revealed to have followed them.

Comment: If so, it would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186382/cartoon-network-show-monster-hunting-dark-theme-monsters-looked-to-be-done-by/186386#186386